# Javascript - Assign dynamic string to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to assign to withdraw the name of a variable from a dynamic string.

Ex. 
Thats wright:

```
 Item.text = localizedStrings.report_label;
```

Thats wrong:

```
var localizedName = "localizedStrings.report_".concat(tempList[index].Name);
Item.text = localizedName;
```

Can someone tell me the way to do that??

Comment: of course, the secont part is inside a cycle for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):-

```
var localizedName = localizedStrings["report_" + tempList[index].Name];
Item.text = localizedName;
```